# PHP combine multiple array into one with key

Tags: php, arrays

I am lost actually, not sure how to explain the question.

Suppose I have three array

```
$name = array('mark', 'jones', 'alex');
$age  = array(12, 23, 34);
$country = array('USA', 'UK', 'Canada');
```

What I am looking for is:

```
array(
0 => array(
  'name' => 'mark',
  'age' => 12,
  'country' => 'USA'
  )
1 => array(
  'name' => 'jones',
  'age' => 23,
  'country' => 'UK'
  )
2 => array(
  'name' => 'alex',
  'age' => 34,
  'country' => 'Canada'
);
```

Couldn't figure out any built in PHP array function to handle it.

Comment: PHP has a lot of built-in functions, but you'll find yourself _writing your own_ just as much (or more).

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
$result = array();

foreach($name as $key => $value)
{
   $result[$key] = array (
      'name'    => $value, 
      'age'     => $age[$key], 
      'country' => $country[$key]
   );
}
echo '<pre>';

print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without any manual looping like this:

```
// array_map with null callback merges corresponding items from each input
$merged = array_map(null, $name, $age, $country);

// walk over the results to change array_map's numeric keys to strings
$keys = ['name', 'age', 'country'];
array_walk(
    $merged, 
    function(&$row) { $row = array_combine(['name', 'age', 'country'], $row); }
);

print_r($merged);
```

You can even write it in such a way that the keys in the result are equal to the names of the variables `$name`, `$age`, `$country` without needing to repeat yourself:

```
// Here "name", "age" and "country" appear only once:
$inputs = compact('name', 'age', 'country');
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_map', [null] + $inputs);
$keys = array_keys($inputs);
array_walk(
    $merged, 
    function(&$row) use($keys) { $row = array_combine($keys, $row); }
);
```

However, to be frank it might be more readable (and it might even be faster) to just `for` over the inputs (assuming they have the same number of items) and do it manually.